# Laravel 5 - Customize JSON response on a Rest API server

Tags: php, json, laravel-5

I am completely new on Laravel, I am migrating my application from Slim Framework to, indeed, Laravel 5.
Googling I haven't find much information about how to customize a JSON response. Let's say I have:

**MODEL**

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class User extends Model
{
    protected $visible = [
        'username', 'posts',
    ]; 
}
```

**CONTROLLER**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use [...]

/* *
 *  Implicit controller
 */
class UserController extends Controller
{
    public function getIndex()
    {
        return response()->json(User::all(), 200);
    }
}
```

**ROUTE**

```
Route::controller('users', 'UserController');
```

What if I want to output that data in a JSON object like:

```
{"success": bool, "message": string, "data": array} 
// in this case 'array' would be User::all()
```

?

Does anyone know whether there's a library to handle this kind of stuff? Or Has anyone already addressed this in laravel somehow?

N.B. I know I can write a Middleware to "modify" the response, but I am not sure it is the right solution, and it is also painful to check into the middleware whether the response should contain an error or not.

Thank you.

Answer (score 14):

Is a kinda late response but maybe it'll be helpfull for someone further.

You can solve this with a Response Factory creating a Provider on your project, here is an example for **Success** and **Error** responses:

```
<?php
// Place this file on the Providers folder of your project
namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;
use Illuminate\Routing\ResponseFactory;

class ResponseServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * Bootstrap the application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot(ResponseFactory $factory)
    {
        $factory->macro('success', function ($message = '', $data = null) use ($factory) {
            $format = [
                'status' => 'ok',
                'message' => $message,
                'data' => $data,
            ];

            return $factory->make($format);
        });

        $factory->macro('error', function (string $message = '', $errors = []) use ($factory){
            $format = [
                'status' => 'error', 
                'message' => $message,
                'errors' => $errors,
            ];

            return $factory->make($format);
        });
    }

    /**
     * Register the application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function register()
    {
        //
    }
}
```

Then on your providers value placed in config/app.php just add the class:

```
'providers' => [
    ...

    App\Providers\ResponseServiceProvider::class,
]
```

And it's done, as the provider is already aggregated, you can just call the macro using the **response helper** passing the respectives attributes. Eg:

```
$user = User::find(1); 

if($user) {
   return response()->success('Your custom success message', $user);
} else {
   return response()->error('Your custom error message', 'Validation errors or else');
}
```

Answer (score 8):

Did You try

```
return response()->json([
    'success'=>true, 
    'message'=>'string', 
    'data'=>User::all()
]);
```

?

Comment: of course it works if I json_encode that array instead of just User:all() .... this is the approach I am currently using on Slim.. I have a static function that accepts data and error arguments, and returns the response array accordingly... what I am searching for is something built into Laravel .. thank you for your interest